# NameError: name 'sideways_target' is not defined

Tags: python

I have an error where python is not able to find my file. (if I understand correctly) I can't find what I have missed. If anyone could take the time to point it out to me, it would be much appreciated.

---

```
def _check_target_edges(self):
        """Respond appropriately if the target has reached an edge."""
        if sideways_target.check_edges():
            self._change_target_direction()
```

this code is giving error messages

```
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.5)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\2\Desktop\python_work\Chapter 11 - 15\Chapter 14\14.2 Target Practice.py", line 218, in <module>
    ss.run_game()
  File "C:\Users\2\Desktop\python_work\Chapter 11 - 15\Chapter 14\14.2 Target Practice.py", line 53, in run_game
    self._update_target()
  File "C:\Users\2\Desktop\python_work\Chapter 11 - 15\Chapter 14\14.2 Target Practice.py", line 157, in _update_target
    self._check_target_edges()
  File "C:\Users\2\Desktop\python_work\Chapter 11 - 15\Chapter 14\14.2 Target Practice.py", line 207, in _check_target_edges
    if sideways_target.check_edges():
NameError: name 'sideways_target' is not defined
[Finished in 2.7s]
```

---

```
def check_edges(self):
        """Return True if target is at edge of screen."""
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom or self.rect.top <= 0:
            return True
```

This is what I want the code to find. So it updates any changes in True/False.
I would like to know where can I define 'sideways_target' so the error clears up and I can run the project.

---

If you need more detail... the files are down below

File of the 1st piece of code

```
# ship spawns on the left side
# bullets travel to the right
# target moves up and down
# shoot the target
# 

import sys, pygame

from sideways_settings import Settings
from sideways_ship import Ship
from sideways_bullet import Bullet
from sideways_game_stats import GameStats
from sideways_target import Target
from sideways_button import Button


class ShipShooter:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.sideways_settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.sideways_settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
        self.sideways_settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().height
        pygame.display.set_caption("Sideways Shooter")

        # Create an instance to store game statistics.
        self.sideways_stats = GameStats(self)

        self.sideways_ship = Ship(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

        # Make the button.
        self.sideways_play_button = Button(self, "Play")

        # Make the target
        self.sideways_target = Target(self)

        # Set the background color.
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()

            if self.sideways_stats.game_active:
                self.sideways_ship.update()
                self._update_bullets()
                self._update_target()

            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                self._check_play_button(mouse_pos)

    def _check_play_button(self, mouse_pos):
        """Start a new game when the player clicks Play."""
        button_clicked = self.sideways_play_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
        if button_clicked and not self.sideways_stats.game_active:
            # Reset the game statistics.
            self.sideways_stats.reset_stats()
            self.sideways_stats.game_active = True

            # Get rid of any remaining bullets.
            self.bullets.empty()

            # Center the ship
            self.sideways_ship.center_ship()

            # Hide the mouse cursor.
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    def _check_play_button2(self):
        """Start a new game when the player clicks Play."""
        if self.key_p == True:
            # Reset the game statistics.
            self.sideways_stats.reset_stats()
            self.sideways_stats.game_active = True

            # Get rid of any remaining bullets.
            self.bullets.empty()

            # Center the ship
            self.sideways_ship.center_ship()

            # Hide the mouse cursor.
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        """Respond to keypresses."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.sideways_ship.moving_up = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.sideways_ship.moving_down = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self._fire_bullet()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_p:
            self.key_p = True
            self._check_play_button2()


    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        """Respond to key releases."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.sideways_ship.moving_up = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.sideways_ship.moving_down = False

    def _fire_bullet(self):
        """Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group."""
        if len(self.bullets) < self.sideways_settings.bullets_allowed:
            new_bullet = Bullet(self)
            self.bullets.add(new_bullet)

    def _update_bullets(self):
        """Update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets."""
        # Update bullet positions.
        self.bullets.update()

        # Get rid of bullets that have disappeared.
        for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.right >= self.sideways_ship.screen_rect.right :
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)
        #   print(len(self.bullets))

        # Look for bullets hitting the side of the screen.
        self._check_bullets_bottom()

    def _check_bullet_target_collisions(self):
        """Respond to bullet-target collisions."""
        # Remove any bullets that have collided with the target
        collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(
                self.bullets, self.sideways_target, True, True)

    def _update_target(self):
        """
        Check if the target is at the edge,
            then update the position of the target
        """
        self._check_target_edges()
        self.sideways_target.update()

        # Look for bullet-target collisions.
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self.bullets, self.sideways_target):
            self._target_hit()

    def _target_hit(self):
        """Respond to the target being hit by a bullet."""
        if self.sideways_stats.targets_left > 0:
            # Decrement targets_left.
            self.sideways_stats.targets_left -= 1

            # Get rid of any remaining bullets.
            self.bullets.empty()

            # Center the ship.
            self.sideways_ship.center_ship()

            # Pause.
            sleep(1.5)
        else:
            self.sideways_stats.game_active = False
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

    def _check_bullets_bottom(self):
        """Check if any bullets have reached the side of your screen."""
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            if bullet.rect.right >= screen_rect.right:
                # Treat this the same as if the target got hit.
                self.target_hit()
                break

    def _update_screen(self):
        """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
        self.screen.fill(self.sideways_settings.bg_color)
        self.sideways_ship.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()
        self.sideways_target.draw_target()

        # Draw the play button if the game is inactive.
        if not self.sideways_stats.game_active:
            self.sideways_play_button.draw_button()     

        pygame.display.flip()

    def _check_target_edges(self):
        """Respond appropriately if the target has reached an edge."""
        if sideways_target.check_edges():
            self._change_target_direction()
            

    def _change_target_direction(self):
        """Change the target's direction."""
        self.sideways_settings.target_direction *= -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    ss = ShipShooter()
    ss.run_game()
```

---

File of the 2nd piece of code

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Target:

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize target attributes."""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()

        # Set the dimensions and properties of the target
        self.width, self.height = 70, 300
        self.target_color = (0, 0, 0)

        # Build the target's rect object and center it.
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        self.rect.midright = self.screen_rect.midright

        # Store the target's exact vertical position.
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def check_edges(self):
        """Return True if target is at edge of screen."""
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom or self.rect.top <= 0:
            return True

    def update(self):
        """Move the target up or down."""
        self.y += (self.sideways_settings.target_speed *
                    self.sideways_settings.target_direction)
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_target(self):
        # Draw the target to the screen
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.target_color, self.rect)
```

Comment: You are checking `if sideways_target.check_edges():` instead of `if self.sideways_target.check_edges():`.

Comment: That cleared up the error. Thank you!

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with an emphasis on minimal.

Comment: I'd say the same but why don't you name it with a suffix like `self.sideways_target_` to make sure you don't sure the same name

Comment: There's no conflict between the global name `sideways_target` referring to a module and an instance attribute with the same name.